# System.IdentityModel.Tokens.UserNameSecurityToken' security token with the 'Basic' attachment mode must be signed

Tags: wcf

I am getting this exception in WCF trace logs when trying to access WCF service using wsHttpBinding. I have not implemented custom security token. Is there any information on this error message. Please advise.
I get this error when calling the service from SoapUI.

The 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.UserNameSecurityToken' security token with the 'Basic' attachment mode must be signed.   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeaderElementManager.EnsureAllRequiredSecurityHeaderTargetsWereProtected()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.ProcessSecurityHeader(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, Message&amp; message, SecurityToken requiredSigningToken, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message&amp; message, String actor, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ServerSecurityChannel`1.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.SecurityReplyChannel.ProcessReceivedRequest(RequestContext requestContext, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.OnInnerReceiveDone()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
   at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
   at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(

Comment: Can you show your app.config file with the WCF configuration in it?

Comment: I get this error when calling the service from SoapUI.